# css styling for select and numeric Input

Tags: css, r, shiny

I am using R shiny and i am trying to set the same heigth for selectInput and numericInput in my ui.
I found this line:

```
 tags$style(type="text/css", ".selectize-input {line-height: 20px;}"),
```

which changes the heigth for all my selectInputs.

Is there any similar line to numericInput?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, it does not have a specific class such as `selectInput`. But you can still get the same result using the more general class `form-control`. We need to use `height` instead of `line-height` though, which will work fine for `selectInput` anyway.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$style(type = "text/css", ".form-control.shiny-bound-input, 
.selectize-input {height: 70px;}"),
  selectInput(inputId = "another_id",
              label = "bar",
              choices = c(1, 2)),
  numericInput(inputId = "some_id",
              label = "foo",
              value = 1)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

### EDIT:

In case you want to apply some CSS to a specific input, you need to use its `id`, so the style does not apply to all elements sharing the same class. In the example above, if you only want to change the height of the `numericInput` whose `id` is `some_id`, you would use `#some_id` to select this element, leading to the following code:

```
tags$style(type = "text/css", 
           "#some_id.form-control.shiny-bound-input {height: 70px;}")
```

Comment: Cool :) Don't hesitate to accept the answer if it worked! Also, if you want to customize shiny UI elements, open your shiny app in a browser like Chrome and inspect the page to identify the class/id of your elements.

Comment: Hello @kluu, how can I make it work for specific input and not all of them?

Comment: Hi @migdalmenora! Please check my edit of the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot @kluu

Comment: just in case anyone is frustrated as i was, if your ids have a period, it will not work. So some_id should not be some.id.... that was a fun couple of hours tearing my hair out... :D